# Using an existing logo?

Tags: copyright, trademark

Can I used an existing logo and put a my own spin on it?
 So I wanted to recreate the logo doublemint gum but instead mines will say DoubleLint. I still want the same design and colors. I want to use it for social media like Instagram for selling used clothing. Is it still illegal if both logo are still similar?

Comment: If the owner of the original logo is a big company and has an army of lawyers who should earn their bread, they can take every penny you get plus a hefty extra as a compensation for caused damage and the costs you have generated. Theoretically it is possible that they do not care for example because you live in the middle of a desert in Africa.

Answer (score 1):

Using *any* copyrighted material, including a logo, to create *new* artwork can be construed as **derivative work** and **copyright infringement**.

There are some general exceptions such as parody, or personal use (fair use). However, actually designing a logo for yourself based upon an established brand would be clear infringement in my opinion. Many companies are bulldogs when it comes down to enforcing their copyrights against others trying to piggy-back off their success. And rightly so in many instances.

For *any* logo or brand **only original artwork** should be used.

Original artwork may be *influenced* by other artwork. However, for a logo the entire point is a *unique* identifier. Disregarding the legal ramifications, why would you want to muddle your own brand and confuse it with an existing brand??